# Increase power of load in AC to DC converter

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, capacitor, current

[image]

Hi readers, above is a ac to dc converter. I want to increase power output of the load and that's why I put the load resistance to be much lower than the series resistance(internal resistance).
However, from my simulation, the voltage series resistance (internal resistance of source) consumes much m**ore power from the source** than my load. **How do I overcome this?**

Comment: Reduce the source internal resistance, of course! Why is it so high?

Comment: What **is** V1+40 ohms, physically?

Comment: Hi,@Transistor, from your experience, what resistance of the output of the step-down tranformer normally? I am thinking of using a super-thick wire which reduces the wire resistance which then reduces the internal resistance of the source. Does thick wire really reduces resistance by a lot of times?

Comment: Hi @ Neil_UK, I am exaggerating it so that you can see the picture clearer. Sorry for inconvininece

Comment: It seems that you are designing a transformer. That means you should be using some design rules. You need to work out the required turns and wiring sizes on both the primaries and secondaries. When you've done that you can calculate the series resistance on both. Don't forget that voltages change by \$ N:n \$ (the turns ratio) that the impedances change by \$ (N:n)^2 \$. This will be explained in any good transformer theory book.

Comment: Hi @Transistor @ Neil_UK, from my simulation if that series resistance is close to 0 (very ideal), the power output of the load will be very high. However, when the series resistance is 1 , lets say, the power output will be extremely low. Does that mean that in real life, tramsformers are very efficient and the output wire resistance is very little to create an ideal zero resistance for max power?

Comment: Try to find a transformer datasheet and look at the open-circuit voltage and the rated voltage which should be quoted at full load. You can then work out the equivalent series resistor value. It has to be low if the transformer is to supply a fairly constant voltage and to avoid wasting power. Don't just guess. Tip: you can only ping one person in each comment. You must use `@username` with no spaces - even if there are spaced in the actual username.

Comment: @Transistor Hi, I have searched for some datasheet. It seems like the bigger the transformer, the lower is the resistance because I believe the coil diameter is bigger.

Comment: "I believe the coil diameter is bigger." Mind the terminology, it's that the **wire** diameter is larger. It would have to be to achieve the required current rating without overheating.

Comment: transformers generally have a very low resistance, which is why they work so well. They are rarely rated to drop more than 6% of their output voltage when going from no load to full load (very small ones might drop more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Use a better, lower resistance, source.

Or put multiple sources in parallel.

Or choose a higher resistance load.

Or supply the load with a lower voltage by using a buck SMPS after C1 before the load.

Or increase C1 and add a load switch so you can supply the load intermittently, charging up C1 to V1peak between shots.

As you have a sinewave source, and if the 40 ohm resistance represents miles of feeder from a remote power supply, use a transformer to increase the voltage before the feeder, and decrease it after, which reduces the effective resistance of the feeder by N<sup>2</sup> where N is the transformer ratio.

Which of these mitigations is suitable will be determined by what exactly your diagram represents, and what your constraints are.